# Delete and replace a Specific Line in .txt file

Tags: c++, file-handling

I'm struggling with my C++ project related to file handling and need one help.

### Here is my movies.txt file

```
SNO, Name, NoOfPeopleLiked
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77 
2, The Godfather, 20        
3, Into The Wild, 35
4, The Dark Knight, 55      
5, 12 Angry Men, 44     
6, Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32   
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
```

I want to delete the specific line by just inputting the movie name of that line. For **Example** when I input movie name "**12 Angry Men**" The whole line no 5 should be deleted and replaced with the updated line having incremented **`NoOfPeopleLiked`** values from `5, 12 Angry Men, 44` to `5, 12 Angry Men, 45`.
How can I delete that specific line and update the liked value whenever I input movie name?

---

But When I input the movie name all lines get deleted till line no 6 and the **output** file looked like this.

---

```
    , Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32   
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
```

---

Kindly help me to resolve this issue?
Here is my code:

```
void search()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("movies.txt");
    cout << "Enter the name of Movie : " << ' ';
    getline(cin, search_movie);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file, line, ','))
        {
            if ((line.find(search_movie, 0)) != string::npos)
            {
                file >> liked;
                file >> serial;
                cout << serial << " The movie '" << search_movie << "' has been found in database and " << liked << " people like this movie" << endl;
                cout << "Do you like it as well (y/n)" << ' ';
                char z;
                cin >> z;
                if (z == 'y' || z == 'Y')
                {
                    update(search_movie, file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "your file could not be opened" << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

---

```
    void update(string search_movie, ifstream& file1)
    {
        ofstream temp;
        string linee;
        temp.open("temp.txt", ios::out);
        while (getline(file1, linee))
        {
            cout << linee << endl;
            if (line.substr(0, search_movie.size()) != search_movie)
            {
                temp << linee << endl;
            }
        }
        file1.close();
        temp.close();
        remove("movies.txt");
        rename("temp.txt", "movies.txt");
    }
};
```

Comment: Simple strategy for this kind of task. 1) Read the whole file into a vector or array. 2) Make the change you want to the vector (or array) 3) Write the whole vector (or array) back out to file. The way you are trying to do it cannot work.

Comment: You need to copy all content of the first file, remove the one line, and then output the rest into the same file

Comment: Your code has another problem you haven't noticed yet. Where you read the name, you read stopping at a comma. So when you try to read in (for one example): "9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32   ", it's going to read only "The Good" as the title. From there it looks like it'll try to treat `the Bad and the ugly, 32` as the number of likes, which probably won't work very well.

Comment: @john 1) reading the whole file into a vector is potentially not a good idea, since the file can be huge. It certainly would require to check the size and read it in chunks. 2) It is not necessary to write the whole file back, you need to write only the rest of the file starting from modified position. That also might be expensive if the file is huge and is modified at the beginning. I've wrote an answer how it can be done without overwriting big chunks of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you want to do: it increments the number of likes for a movie. It **does not** store the contents of the whole file into the buffer. The file might be of a large size, so it might not be very efficient.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{
    std::fstream fileMovies{"sample.txt",
                            std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary};
    if (!fileMovies.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string movieName{};
    std::getline(std::cin, movieName);

    std::string line{};
    line.reserve(256);

    long long int pos = fileMovies.tellp();
    for (line; std::getline(fileMovies, line);)
    {
        if (line.find(movieName) != std::string::npos)
            break;
        line.clear();
        pos = fileMovies.tellp();
    }

    if (fileMovies.eof())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to find the movie by name" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    long long int curPos = fileMovies.tellp();

    // TODO: check format
    long long int commaPos = line.rfind(',');
    fileMovies.seekp(pos + commaPos + 2);

    int liked = 0;
    fileMovies >> liked;
    fileMovies.seekp(pos + commaPos + 2);
    fileMovies << ++liked;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\dev\builds\editfile\Release-Visual Studio\bin> cat .\sample.txt
SNO, Name, NoOfPeopleLiked
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77
2, The Godfather, 20
3, Into The Wild, 35
4, The Dark Knight, 55
5, 12 Angry Men, 44
6, Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
PS C:\dev\builds\editfile\Release-Visual Studio\bin> .\main.exe
Angry
PS C:\dev\builds\editfile\Release-Visual Studio\bin> cat .\sample.txt
SNO, Name, NoOfPeopleLiked
1, The Shawshank Redemption, 77
2, The Godfather, 20
3, Into The Wild, 35
4, The Dark Knight, 55
5, 12 Angry Men, 45
6, Schindler's List, 33
7, The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King, 25
8, Pulp Fiction, 23
9, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, 32
10, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, 56
```

***Keep in mind***, that you ***can't*** append new characters in the middle of the file (nor can you erase them). You can only **overwrite** the existing ones at the current position.
So in order for this to work properly, you should use the number of likes with trailing spaces, or in format like `0045`.
Also, pay attention that you have to use `std::fstream` with flags `in | out | binary`. Binary is necessary in order to properly count the current position.